# Is it true that exaggerating love will lead you to shirk?

Tags: shirk, love

I was wonder that exagerrating love will lead you to shirk?I mean Christians love Jesus Christ(pbuh)then slowly by slowly they made him as a god because of too much love,is it true?

Comment: "Will lead you to shirk - this is not always true, it *can* lead to shirk but it doesnt have to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. In islam, muslims are stricly ordered not to praise the Prophets so much that they give them status near to or like or even Above God.

Here is one hadith about it:

> Umar ibn Al-Khattab reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and
>   blessings be upon him, said, “Do not exaggerate my praises as the
>   Christians have done with the son of Mary. Verily, I am only a
>   servant, so refer to me as the servant of Allah and his messenger.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3261